# FFMPEG: how to enable overlay filter until the end of the video? (not knowing duration)

Tags: video, ffmpeg, time, watermark

I'd like some help for a project I'm working for using FFmpeg (not an expert in video editing at all!!).

BASIC IDEA
I have a lot of videos in a folder and I would like to compress them + to add a short video disclaimer before each video + to add a logo as an overlay during all the video (but not during the disclaimer, which is about 12 seconds). Presently I'm using this:

```
ffmpeg -i intro.mpg -i video.avi -i logo.png  -filter_complex "[0:v][0:a][1:v][1:a]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[vid1];[vid1][2:v]overlay=W-w-5:H-h-5:enable='between(t,12,300)'[vid2]" -map "[vid2]" -strict -2 -c:v libx265 -x265-params crf=28 -preset ultrafast -movflags faststart output.mp4
```

It works, however, I have to use the same command for a lot of videos and I don't know the duration of them (my plan is to use something as `for i in *.avi; do ffmpeg -i "$i" "${i%.*}.mp4"; done`).

Any way to set the filter `enable='between(t,12,X)'` setting **X** duration such as 'until the end of the video'?
Many thanks!

ADVANCED

A solution to the previous issue is good enough, however, I was wondering... Could it be possible to have the logo.png overlay shifting position after a certain amount of time, until the end of the movie? For instance, 10 minutes as `overlay=W-w-5:H-h-5`, then 10 minutes `overlay=5:H-h-5`, then 10' in `overlay=5:5`, finally `overlay=W-w-5:5` and again a new loop starting from bottom-right... 
Maybe starting from something like this? `enable=lt(mod(t\,3)\,1)` (no idea where to find friendly documentation about filters...)
Thank you again!

Daniele

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
overlay=W-w-5:H-h-5:enable='gt(t,12)'
```

For shifting overlays in counter-clockwise direction, every ten minutes i.e. 600 seconds,

`overlay='5+mod(trunc(((t-12)+1200)/1200),2)*(W-w-10)':'5+mod(trunc(((t-12)+1800)/1200),2)*(H-h-10)':enable='gt(t,12)'`

Comment: The solution was... "just don't specify the ending time"... shame on me! :-) Thanks a lot also for the solution to issue no.2, it works perfectly. Could you explain to me a little the code or indicate me where I could find documentation? I can't understand 5+mod and trunc command... Thank you again!

Comment: See the functions here: https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-utils.html#Expression-Evaluation. Basically, I alter the x and y values independently every 20 minutes (the y is 10 minutes out-of-phase).

Comment: @Gyan, I am using best quality png image for watermark to add it on an video but after placing watermark icon on video, watermark icon is blurred, what is reason and how can i fix this issue, please suggest. Thanks in advance.